# Why does returning shared_ptr<T> as shared_ptr<const T> result in "returning address of temporary" warnings?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
class Example
{
    boost::shared_ptr<FilterProvider> filterProvider;
public:
    void RegisterFilter(const boost::shared_ptr<FilterProvider>& toRegister)
    {
        filterProvider = toRegister;
    }
    const boost::shared_ptr<const FilterProvider>& GetFilter() const
    {
        return filterProvider; // Compiler reports "Returning address of local
                               // variable or temporary"
    }
};
```

I don't see what's local or temporary about `filterProvider` here; I'm returning what looks like a member variable of the class, not a temporary. (If I was actually returning a local variable or something like that the warning would make sense)

The specific warning is:

```
warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your shared ptr is declared with type

```
boost::shared_ptr<FilterProvider>
```

You are returning

```
boost::shared_ptr<const FilterProvider>
```

by const reference. See the difference?

The types are not the same, but the former is convertible to the latter, and the compiler invokes the conversion. The result of the conversion is not an lvalue, but rather a temporary object, meaning that you are returning a const reference bound to a temporary object. This is legal initialization-wise, but the temporary will be destroyed right before the function returns. So in the calling code the reference will be invalid, which is what the compiler is warning you about.

Comment: There are multiple correct answers. Checking this one because it was the first posted.

Answer (score 4):

`filterProvider` is of type `boost::shared_ptr<FilterProvider>`, but you're returning (a reference to) `boost::shared_ptr<const FilterProvider>` (note the `const`). These types are not the same as far as the compiler is concerned. However, an implicit conversion exists. This causes the compiler to make a temporary instead, and you're returning the reference to that temporary, not to the `shared_ptr` itself.

But why are you handing out a reference to a `shared_ptr` in the first place? Either hand out a copy of the `shared_ptr`, or, if you want to prevent modification, hand out a `const` reference to the underlying `FilterProvider` object.

Comment: I want to hand out the object, but it's possible when someone asks that the filter has not yet been set. Therefore calling code needs to be able to get the null reference.

Comment: @Pavel: Then they can modify the target object, which I don't want them to be able to do.

Comment: To be more precise, hand out a pointer-to-`const`. In other words, same as what you do already, just drop that `&`.

Answer (score 2):

`filterProvider` is a shared pointer to a `FilterProvider`, but `GetFilter()` returns a reference to a shared pointer to a `const FilterProvider`.

While, for example, an `int` can be treated as a `const int&`, the same does not hold true for templates. A `Foo<Bar>` is not in any way related to a `Foo<const Bar>` and so cannot be treated as a `Foo<const Bar>&`.

Boost provides a *conversion* from `shared_ptr<T>` to `shared_ptr<const T>`, but this conversion involves creating a new temporary object of type `shared_ptr<const T>`.

So what is happening here is that you are trying to return a `shared_ptr<FilterProvider>` from a function that wants to return a `shared_ptr<const FilterProvider>&`. This invokes an explicit conversion which creates a new temporary object of type `shared_ptr<const FilterProvider>` and then a reference to that is returned. Therefore, you are returning a reference to a temporary.